# Here Maps iOS SDK: Change the colour of sublegs in a route

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, here-api, here-maps-rest, here-ios

I would like to know if it is possible to give different colors to different sub legs in a route using Here maps iOS SDK. I saw `upcomingColor` and `traveledColor` property in `NMAMapRoute.h` class but didn't see any documentation on how the traveled route and upcoming route are calculated. In my use case, I have to plot at least 3 colors to 3 different sub legs of my route. One thing I saw during my investigation is `NMAMapPolyline` class. Can I use this to draw a route between waypoints? Did it cause any performance issues?.

I will appreciate if someone can provide insight into these.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `color` property, you can change the color of the whole route (not parts) drawn on the map.

With the `traveledColor` property, you can change the color of the part of the route you have travelled so far (so from you start waypoint to the current location on the route).

With the `upcomingColor` property, you can change the color of the next waypoint to the final destination.

Apart from these, the SDK does not support changing random parts of the route out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use NMAMapPolyline for my case?

Comment: If you want to draw the routes yourself, then yes you can use the NMAMapPolyline class.